# Can git keep the line endings in my working directory the same as in the repository?

Tags: git

I would like to commit a file with `CRLF` line endings, for it to stored in the repository with `LF` line endings and either:

1. `git status` shows the file as modified.
2. The file in the working directory is updated to contain `LF` line endings.

Is git intended to accommodate this sort of behaviour?

---

I have tried a `.gitattributes` file in the repository, with `* text=auto`.

This converts line endings in text files from `CRLF` to `LF` when committing, but doesn't ensure matching line endings between the working directory and repository.

Note: I am on Windows, using cygwin with git 1.7.9.

Answer (score 0):

If you delegate line handling to git, then git can take care of converting your CRLF to LF when you commit and when you checkout it will again convert LF to CRLF. So you wont see files as changed just because of line ending changes. To do this have your global config set as `git config --global core.autocrlf true`.

Reference from the manual - http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace